# Test Coverage 93% how to Make this code cover to 100%

Tags: trigger, unit-test

```
public class TriggerClass {
public void Mycodecoverage(Branch__c Mycodecoverage)
{
string BankId = Mycodecoverage.Project_Bank__c;
List<Bank__c> bank = [select id,project__c,project__r.name,bank_Description__c from Bank__c where id =: BankId];

string BankName = bank[0].Project__r.name;
system.debug('---> Project Name --->'+BankName);
string bankDescription = bank[0].bank_Description__c;
string MycodecoverageComment = Mycodecoverage.Comment__c;
system.debug('---> bank Update Comment --->'+MycodecoverageComment);

List<Bank__c> banklist = [select id,name,bank_Description__c,bank_Owner__c,bank_Owner__r.email from Bank__c where id =: BankId];
String bankOwnerEmail = '';
String bankOwnerId = '';

if(banklist.size()>0 && banklist[0].bank_Owner__c != null && banklist[0].bank_Owner__r.email != null)
{
bankOwnerEmail = banklist[0].bank_Owner__r.email;
bankOwnerId = banklist[0].bank_Owner__c;
}
String currentOwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();

List<User> user = [select id,name,email from User where id =: currentOwnerId];
String currentownerEmail = user[0].Email;
List<String> Emails = new List<String>();
Emails.add(bankOwnerEmail);

if(bankOwnerId != currentOwnerId){
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = Emails;
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setBccSender(true);
mail.setUseSignature(false);
String Esubject = bankDescription + '/' + BankName;
mail.setSubject(Esubject);
mail.setPlainTextBody(MycodecoverageComment);
mail.saveAsActivity=false;
mail.setTargetObjectId (UserInfo.getUserId());
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
}

}
@isTest
private static void TriggerClass()
{
trg_TriggerClass branchClass= new TriggerClass ();

Account account = new Account();
account.name = 'test account';
try{
insert account;
}
catch(exception e){}
system.assertnotequals(account ,null);

Project__c project = new Project__c();
project.name = 'test project';
project.Account__c = account.id;
try{
insert project;
}
catch(exception e){}
system.assertnotequals(project,null);

//String currentOwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();                   (if i remove the comment for this )


Bank__c TestBank= new Bank__c();
TestBank.Name = 'test branch';
TestBank.Project__c = project.Id;
TestBank.branch_Description__c = 'test';
//TestBank.branch_Owner__c = currentOwnerId;               (and remove comment for this then two red lines are covering but Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); to---------  Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail } is not covering )
try{  
insert TestBank;
}
catch(exception e){}
system.assertnotequals(TestBank,null);

Branch__C branch= new Branch__C();
branch.Project_Bank__c= TestBank.Id;
branch.Make_Public__c = true ;
branch.Comment__c = '';
try
{
insert branch;
}
catch(exception e){}
system.assertnotequals(branch,null );

}
}
```

Comment: First, please format this for easier reading. Secondly, SF provides highlighting of which lines of code are covered and which are missed. Please provide that or people will not be able to suggest solutions.

Comment: these lines are in red colour       String bankOwnerEmail = ''; String bankOwnerId = '';

Comment: Have you tried clearing the code coverage from the Apex Classes page listing, compiling all classes, and then going into the individual test class that you think should give coverage, run the test, and then inspect the coverage?  Sometimes the reported coverage can get out of synch with actual coverage.

Answer (score 3):

When you go to your apex classes in salesforce you should see the code coverage of the specific class right next to your classname:

[image: apex classes]

then when you click the percentage displaying the code coverage you should see the class with each line colored depending on did the line of code got included in the code coverage, blue = yes, red = no.

[image: class description]

this way you can perfectly see which lines are covered and which aren't.

Comment: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Test-Coverage-93-how-to-Make-this-code-cover-to-100/m-p/536705/highlight/false#M97416 there is the link of my test code

Comment: here is the link of my code

Comment: Perhaps provide us with the lines you are having trouble with? You really can't expect us to write your code coverage for you based on a class you provide.

Comment: You must also understand that we don't have your salesforce setup and adding all your fields and functionality just to reach your last 7% it's a bit mad. However, if you provide us with the lines you're having trouble with, i'd be happy to take a look and help where I can. By the way, sometimes 100% code coverage isn't possible due to limitations.

Comment: String bankOwnerEmail = '';
String bankOwnerId = '';                                                        
these lines are not covering

Comment: that is weird, I will take a closer look later

Comment: Im sorry about that actually im not familiar with this site im new to this web site here is the url of my code in other web site, which is much clear                                                [http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Test-Coverage-93-how-to-Make-this-code-cover-to-100/td-p/536661]

Comment: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Test-Coverage-93-how-to-Make-this-code-cover-to-100/td-p/536661